# How delete sms message from Android. Rad studio

Tags: android, delphi, sms

How delete sms message from Android? Code from Rad studio.
I can read the message, get the information - Id message, address, body text.
When I press the Button1, the message should be deleted. But this did not happen. Android does not issue nor any mistakes.

**This does not work. What am I doing wrong?**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var uri_del: Jnet_Uri;
begin
if listbox1.ItemIndex>-1 then begin
timer1.Enabled:=false;
cursms.close;
showmessage(sms[listbox1.ItemIndex].body);
uri_del:= StrToJURI('content://sms/');
SharedActivity.getContentResolver.delete(uri_del, StringToJString('_ID=' + sms[listbox1.ItemIndex].smsid), nil);
showmessage('Delete!');
timer1.Tag:=0;
timer1.Interval:=10;
timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var CallDate: Int64;
uri: Jnet_Uri;

 id_smsid: integer;
  id_smssender: integer;
  id_smsbody: integer;
begin
timer1.Enabled:=false;
if (timer1.Tag=0) then begin
uri:= StrToJURI('content://sms/');
 cursms:= SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, nil, nil, nil);

 if cursms.getCount<>length(sms) then begin
 setlength(sms,0);
 timer1.Tag:=1;
 timer1.Interval:=10;
 listbox1.Clear;
 end;
end else begin

if (cursms.getCount > 0) then
if cursms.getCount>length(sms)  then begin
cursms.moveToNext;
setlength(sms,length(sms)+1);

id_smsid:= cursms.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('_ID'));
  id_smssender:= cursms.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('address'));
  id_smsbody:=cursms.getColumnIndex(StringToJstring('body'));

 sms[length(sms)-1].phone:=JStringToString(cursms.getString(id_smssender));
 sms[length(sms)-1].body:=JStringToString(cursms.getString(id_smsbody));
 sms[length(sms)-1].smsid:=JStringToString(cursms.getString(id_smsid));

 listbox1.Items.Add(sms[length(sms)-1].body);

end else begin
cursms.close;
timer1.Interval:=10000;
timer1.Tag:=0;
end;

end;
timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
```

Comment: What version of Android?  In Kit Kat and later access to SMS was severely restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the database (e.g. delete SMS, create threads, insert messages etc.) your app needs to be set to be the default SMS app on the device. This restriction applies from KitKat.